# Canvas inside VueSlickCarousel

Tags: canvas, nuxt.js

I am using canvas element inside [Vue carousel](https://github.com/gs-shop/vue-slick-carousel). Works fine, but when I resize the window, some of the graphs are not rendered.

Error says that

> canvas with ID="xy" is already in use

`Carousel.vue`

```html
<template>
  <VueSlickCarousel v-bind="settings" class="carousel">
    <template v-for="c in crypto">
      <div :key="c.id" style="display: flex; justify-content: center">
        <div class="crypto-card">
          <div class="header">
            <div class="left">
              <v-img
                :style="`--color_fill: #000;`"
                :src="`/coins/${c.icon}`"
                class="ma-auto"
                width="47px"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="right">
              <h3>{{ c.name }}</h3>
              <h4>{{ c.symbol }}</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p>
            {{
              c.description.length > 100
                ? `${c.description.slice(0, 100)}...`
                : c.description
            }}
          </p>
          <Graph :graph="c.graph" :api-string="c.apiString" />
          <div class="footer">
            <div class="left">
              <h4>${{ c.usd.toLocaleString('en-US') }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
              <span
                :style="c.change < 0 ? 'color: #FF3333' : 'color: #00B67A;'"
              >
                {{ Math.round((c.change + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100 }}%
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </VueSlickCarousel>
</template>
```

`Graph.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div :id="`${graph}Container`">
    <canvas :id="graph" width="800" height="320" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  props: {
    graph: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
    apiString: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  mounted() {
    this.draw()
  },
  methods: {
    draw() {
      axios
        .get(
          `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${this.apiString}/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=7&interval=dayly`
        )
        .then((res) => {
          const responseData = res.data
          const labels = responseData.prices.map(function (e) {
            return new Date(e[0])
          })
          const data = responseData.prices.map(function (e) {
            return e[1]
          })

          const ctx = document.getElementById(this.graph).getContext('2d')
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 320)

          const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 70)
          gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(233, 204, 0, 1)')
          gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(233, 204, 0, 0)')

          const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            responsive: true,
            data: {
              labels,
              datasets: [
                {
                  labelsColor: 'red',
                  backgroundColor: gradient,
                  borderColor: '#EACC23',
                  color: 'transparent',
                  label: 'Numbers',
                  fill: true,
                  radius: 0,
                  data,
                },
              ],
            },
            options: {
              plugins: {
                legend: {
                  display: false,
                },
                labels: {
                  display: false,
                },
              },
              scales: {
                y: {
                  display: false, // Hide Y axis labels
                },
                x: {
                  display: false, // Hide X axis labels
                },
              },
            },
          })

          console.log(myChart)
          window.addEventListener('resize', this.changeCanvas)
        })
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

I read in documentation that I am supposed to call `.destroy()` on `myChart`. But it doesn't work if I save the reference in `data()` to `myChart` nor when I add an event listener on resize.
How can I render those graphs?

Comment: I've edited your question to have something more readable.

Comment: This is quite specific and would be hard to debug with just this amount of code IMO. Do you have a [repro] on Codesandbox or somewhere on Github?